# What is the meaning of WiFiActivity here in android p2p connection? i am getting error in my adt bundle eclips when typing this

Tags: java, android

I need to understand the meaning of private WiFiDirect activity in this code

```
package com.mgamerzproductions.wifidirecttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important wifi p2p events.
 */
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;


    private Channel channel;

    private WiFiActivity activity;



    /**

     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
     * @param Host class (HostSend) for this constructor.
     */

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,

            HostSend activity) {

        super();

        this.manager = manager;

        this.channel = channel;

        this.activity = activity;

    }


    /**
     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
     * @param activity activity associated with the receiver

     */

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,

            ClientReceive activity) {

        super();

        this.manager = manager;

        this.channel = channel;

        this.activity = activity;

    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {



            // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.

            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);

            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {

                // Wifi Direct mode is enabled

                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);

            } else {

                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);

                //activity.resetData();



            }

            Log.d(Launch.APPTAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {


            // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an

            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a

            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()

            if (manager != null) {

                /*manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()

                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));*/

            }

            Log.d(Launch.APPTAG, "P2P peers changed");

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {


            if (manager == null) {

                return;

            }


            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent

                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);



            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {


                // we are connected with the other device, request connection

                // info to find group owner IP


                HostSend connectionListener = activity;

                manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, connectionListener);

            } else {

                // It's a disconnect

                activity.resetData();

            }

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {


            /*DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()



                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);

            fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(

                    WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));*/

        }
    }
```

Even i cant understand it from android devloper zone. I just want to know what that private WiFiActivity activity means and what is it stands for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

What you're seeing here is the name of the main activity created for the app that *is* the tutorial. No different than when you start a new application and choose a name. This is what the developer page has done. So either change all instances of the activity with your name, or simply name your activity the same. Don't forget to add missing items like `.TAG` that appear in the tutorial as well as any thing useful to you.

The tutorials aren't explained line by line. You will have to think a bit and figure some things out. In most cases they will detail anything that benefits from it, other things will be inferred.

**Concerning setIsWifiEnabled():**

This is what you need...

```
...
boolean isWifiEnabled;
...
public void setIsWifiEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
   isWifiEnabled = isEnabled;
}
//add public getter as well
...
```

Comment: Well i am new on android . . so does this means i have to create an activity and then refer that activity with this code Ex : private <my_personal_activity> activity; ???

Comment: and they are calling a methode activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true); but whenever i call this methode i see no suggesstion in eclips.

Comment: Seems like you're following a modified tutorial. `setIsWifiEnabled()` is a field you have to add to the activity. It does not exist in any Android classes that I've been able to find. So, when I did the tutorial, I added. Everything worked out fine.

Comment: Sir i was following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html but when it didn't worked i started searching about info on other websites

Comment: @user127467: See the large edit to the answer; I figured it out.

Comment: @user127467: No problem, if you found the info useful, it's typical to upvote and/or accept it as a correct answer.